# PyTorch - RuntimeError: transform: failed to synchronize: cudaErrorIllegalAddress

Tags: python, deep-learning, gpu, pytorch

I have the problem that when I run my model on Google Colab I very frequently get this error:

```
RuntimeError: transform: failed to synchronize: cudaErrorIllegalAddress: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

I does not happen all the time. Sometimes it works fine but then again it doesn't. 
*(If it works or not seems to be related to the batch size, see edit at the bottom.)*

When running only on **CPU** there is no problem, so it seems related to **GPU/CUDA**.

The error traceback shows that the error happens at some point during `backward()`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c8bbb05fb58a> in <module>()
     65 out   = model(chars, pos)
     66 loss  = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out, labels)
---> 67 loss.backward()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    164                 products. Defaults to ``False``.
    165         """"""
--> 166         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    167 
    168     def register_hook(self, hook):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
     97     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
     98         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
---> 99         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    100 
    101 

RuntimeError: transform: failed to synchronize: cudaErrorIllegalAddress: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

Once this error has occurred I cannot do anything related with GPU on that runtime. Whenever I try then to create some tensors or so on GPU then I get a slightly different error message:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

I need to restart the runtime/notebook in order to do something on the GPU (with Pytorch haven't tried other frameworks).

Here is a code snippet that should be able to reproduce the issue in Google Colab:

```
import os
#os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = '1'

import torch
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(torch.__version__, torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, char_vocab, num_pos, dim, hidden, dropout):
        super().__init__()
        self.emb_char  = nn.Embedding(char_vocab, dim)
        self.cnn1 = nn.Conv1d(dim, dim // 2, kernel_size=3)
        self.bn1  = nn.BatchNorm1d(dim // 2)
        self.cnn2 = nn.Conv1d(dim // 2, dim // 4, kernel_size=2)
        self.bn2  = nn.BatchNorm1d(dim // 4)
        self.pooling = nn.MaxPool1d(2)
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(11, hidden)
        self.bn3  = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(hidden, dim // 4)
        self.bn4  = nn.BatchNorm1d(dim // 4)



        self.out  = nn.Linear(dim // 4, 1)
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, chars, pos):
        x = self.emb_char(chars).transpose(1, 2)
        x = self.drop(x)

        x = self.cnn1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.pooling(x)
        x = F.relu(x)

        x = self.cnn2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.pooling(x).squeeze(-1)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.drop(x)


        y = F.relu(self.lin1(pos))
        y = self.bn3(y)
        y = self.drop(y)
        y = F.relu(self.lin2(y))
        y = self.bn4(y)
        y = self.drop(y)

        return self.out(x+y)

model = MyModel(char_vocab=80, num_pos=11, dim=32, hidden=8, dropout=0.5).to(device)

batch_size = 160000

# inputs
chars = torch.randint(0, 79, (batch_size, 8), device=device)
pos   = torch.rand(batch_size, 11, device=device)

# labels
labels = torch.ones(batch_size, 1, dtype=torch.float, device=device)

# forward
out   = model(chars, pos)
loss  = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out, labels)

# backward
loss.backward()
```

Pytorch version is `1.3.1` the GPU it was running on was `P100-PCIE-16GB`.

**Any ideas how to get rid of this error?**

---

**Edit:**

- I added a piece of code with generated input that can reproduce the issue.
- It seems to be related to the high batch size I'm using. The batch size of `160000` I'm using in the code seems to reliably cause this error, however I noticed that it does not solely depend on the batch size. I tried to reduce it down to `80000` and still got this error. But I know that in my previous runs I have had higher batch sizes up to `180000` without problems. Also starting with a batch size of `60000` worked, then using the same runtime I could run it again with an increased batch size of `140000` without error (that failed before). 
  *Note that the memory usage is very low / only ~1-2 GB*
- Setting `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1` leads to a different error message:

  ```
  RuntimeError: fractional_max_pool2d_backward_out_cuda failed with error code 0
  ```

  But at the same point in code and with same traceback.

Comment: Hi, can you post the full script (maybe try to reduce it to the minimal code that reproduces the error) so that we can try to run it ourselves to help you out? My bet is that you have some ground truth that may behave as an index out of range for your model output

Comment: also, can you run your script with `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1`?

Comment: @iacolippo Thanks again for your suggestions. I edited the question including some code that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I seem to be having the same problem

Comment: @gorjan Unfortunately not. I worked around it.. But this issue and the linked issues may be helpful for you: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4107